# Posterous API, new post with special characters in title

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters, posterous

I'm writing a script to drag all of my images from TwitPic to Posterous but I'm having problems with the some of the characters in the title, here's an example:

```
"My awesome title --> some more text"
```

So when I run the title through `urlencode()` it appears on the Posterous site as `My awesome title --&gt; some more text`, if I don't run it through the `urlencode()` anything after the `>` is stripped, as you'd expect.

I've also tried to use `htmlspecialchars()` and similar with little success, if I email or use the web interface to enter a post any special characters are displayed properly.

I just want my title to match that of the TwitPic image title... but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Cheers, Ben

Comment: You might want to direct help@posterous.com at this question as they are more likely to know the answer.

Comment: I'll try that, wasn't sure if I wasn't understanding character encoding properly... must learn more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god... *hangs head in shame*...

The content returned from the TwitPic API already hasd the HTML chars as `&gt;` etc... ran the title through `html_entitiy_decode()` and it worked perfectly.

Oh well, nobody died I guess.